# Dependency Injection in WPF and Asp.Net Core

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using Asp.Net Core to write API Layer for one of my legacy application developed using WPF (.Net Framework 4.5). I have used https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ in Business layer which I want to access from WPF application. The version of this DI is not supported by .Net Framework 4.5 so I am unable to use it from WPF. Any suggestions how should I go with this ? The other approach is to use anyother DI container supported by .Net framework 4.5 and Asp.Net Core

Comment: You can rollback your business layer to version 1.1 of this package, which should be supported in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded my WPF project to .Net Framework 4.6 and rest of the layers are created using .Net Standard Library 2.0.